# Best practice for selenium tests that have add, update, delete functionality

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, nunit, mstest

I have just started writing selenium tests for my asp.net application using MSTests(I triend NUnit, but i didin't see any difference between it and ms...) and I'm liking them so far, except for the part that test fire randomly.

Now I get the part that tests should not be dependant on other tests(!!!), but how will you tests the add, update, delete functionality then if your tests fire randomly and they do not depend on each other?

I can see only 2 ways how to write such a tests:

1. Use OrderedTests, which I don't like.
2. Write one BIG test that does all those things, but then I have a test that does 3 things!

EDIT: I forgot to mention I don't mock. I want my test to work with my test database.

Answer (score 0):

Ordered test is not a good idea, because in multicore processors we can enable multiple test to be run simultaneously. This is very much helpful in case of build servers and help the tests to be run very quickly and efficiently. Ordered test case will break anyways and not a good idea.

Option 2 is the preferred approach, but I wont call them big. Because apart from the class/functionality you are testing should have been mocked. If you are mocking them and written properly they will be contain only

1. enabling/producing the the test conditions
2. logic for assertion

What I mean to say is, if all dependencies are mocked properly every test case will be small and could be executed within half a second.

In short, your unit test will consist of 3 parts and they should be independent of each other.

1. Common stuff which will go into initialize/mock
2. Test method specific condition which will be in beginning of each test case
3. Assert.

**Edit**

I am sorry to say that if you are using test database, it defeats the purpose of unit test. Unit test is stateless and should be modular. You should be able to test only a small portion of your application functionality without having dependency of other modules. You should test DAL layer/Database access code separately from your application logic.  Databases are stateful and if you tie unit tests to be dependant on database you are integrating two different components and makes it kind of an integration test which will make execution longer and bigger which might be a problem in the longer run.

For now you can go ahead with Option 2. But if you want a better unit test suite, You still need to think about using mocks and separating dependency on database from your unit tests which is going to be a problem in the future. What you can still do is you can write the integration test in a higher level making 20% alone on integration and rest 80% concentrate on unit tests. This way you will be left with faster test cases covering most of the functionalities and easier to maintain. You can compromise on the remaining 20% which are the bigger integration tests and costlier to maintain.

Comment: I kinda forgot to mention that I don't use mocks. I have a separate database for testing, and I want my test to work with a real database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this goes against general practice, but I find little issue with having dependencies in regards to the default order of tests.

In the real world, if you're going through end-to-end testing, use cases will almost always follow the order of add -> edit -> delete.  Users are likely to go through this user journey at least 90% of the time.  I find no problem automating tests in the same fashion to cover these type of odds.

Another alternative would be to populate your database with enough objects so that tests can run independently from one another.

Comment: As mentioned in Jocke comment, I don't get the filling my database with data idea. I wount be able to use static data in my tests (for example delete fires before update, then update will not find an item), thus it will hard to recreate a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Test should not depend on other test, they should be independent. There most important reasons for that is test harness stability and how you should/will react when a test fails. You don't want to start debugging to find out that the "update" test fail because some other test failed...!

Like @Phil suggested population the database could be a way forward. Of course that will/could also be a source of error.

Another way is to provide your test code with "admin" methods/endpoints that for e.g. can create accounts (or what resources your system deals with) and get them in the right state for the actual test. And of course there "admin" functions will also be a source of error.

Wring good and stable Selenuim test are not easy. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think populating the database idea would work. Let's say I have a music shop web app, and I want to add a cd, edit it, and delete it. If my tests fire randomly, I have to put random data in each test (in case my delete fires before update.). But random data tests aren't good, since you cant recreate them easily. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following to be effective when testing Database projects:

- Have a setup for each test. Similar tests can share this functionality, but each test should have a unique identifier for the data being created. So for TestBalanceShopCashUp create a shop called BalanceShopCashUp, BalanceShopCashUpTill01, BalanceShopCashUpTill02, etc.
- Have a generic teardown that is passed the unique identifier which deletes all the test data. This is run at the end of each test regardless of the test succeeding or failing. I have several stored procedures in my databases to do this. They also delete data that reference my identified data.
- Use tools like breakpoints in the debugger to examine the program state at critical points and SQL Server Profiler to check the values being passed to the database.
- I always use stored procedures when interacting with a database. No direct binding to input fields.